# Failed to create OpenGL context. Your graphics card must support at least OpenGL v3.1

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, software-installation, steam

I have successfully installed steam and dota2. But when I try to play dota2 this pops up:

```
Unable to start game.
Failed to create OpenGL context. Your graphics card must support at least OpenGL v3.1
```

My OS is 14.04 LTS 64 bit. My hardware is:

- ASUS H170 Pro gaming MoBo;
- Intel Core i5 6500 Skylake
- 16 GB Ripjaws RAM 2400 CL15;
- Gigabyte GeForce GTX 960 2GB OC Windforce;
- 1 TB western digital 7200 rpm.

How can I fix this/what should I do?

Comment: So - it seems your graphics card (all the other information is unnecessary) supports OpenGL 4.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind. I just updated the driver and it work. I used this:

```
   sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
   sudo reboot 
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
   sudo reboot
```